# Pandas: Concatenate rows with condition

Tags: pandas, python-2.7

I'm trying to do a specific pandas operation but can't figure out how. Suppose the table below is my original table.

| E-mail | Attributes |
| --- | --- |
| js@email | country: US |
| js@email | first: John |
| js@email | display: John |
| js@email | Mark Smith |
| js@email | address: 123 Main St |
| js@email | Baltimore |
| js@email | MD |
| js@email | 12345 |

The rest of the entries are similar for many other users but could potentially be in different order.
The dataframe has over 1.4 million rows. I am trying to get the following output. This can be done in place or by creating a new column(whichever one works better and faster). The example below shows the output if it was performed in place.

| E-mail | Attributes |
| --- | --- |
| js@email | country: US |
| js@email | first: John |
| js@email | display: John, Mark Smith |
| js@email | address: 123 Main St, Baltimore, MD, 12345 |

The rule for getting the following output is as as follows: If there is a `':'` in the `'Attributes'` entry keep the original text, if there is no `':'` in the entry then move that text to the entry above by also adding a `','` in between. Do this until the next entry with `':'`.

The code I am using right now is:

`df['Extended Attributes'].groupby(df['Extended Attributes'].str.contains(':').cumsum()).agg(', '.join)`

However this only returns one column with indices, it doesn't modify the original dataframe and I cannot insert this into the original dataframe as it is because it doesn't have empty rows so there will be mismatch.

Comment: Try `.agg({'Extended Attributes' : ', '.join, 'E-mail' : 'first'})`